# EventListener keydown is working but keyup isn't

Tags: javascript

EventListener keydown is working but keyup is (seemingly) not working. Here is my script:

```
var Keys = [];

var FrameLoop = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
window.webkitrequestAnimationFrame || window.mozrequestAnimationFrame || 
window.msrequestAnimationFrame;
window.requestAnimationFrame = FrameLoop;

window.onload = GameChange();

function GameChange() {
    if (Keys[39] == true) {
        alert("right");
    }
    FrameLoop(GameChange);
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(k) {
    Keys[k.keyCode] = true;
});

document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(k) {
    Keys[k.keyCode] = false;
});
```

As one can see, the code is aiming to alert "right" when the right arrow is clicked and keep doing that till the right arrow key is released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `alert()` is script blocking.

This means that whatever script you were running when it has been called is **paused** at this call, until the user close the alert (same for all other prompt windows).

Add to this that the requestAnimationFrame schedule is executed before the event callbacks loop, and you have an infinite loop of `alert()`, except if you are able to close it before the next screen refresh <sub>(good luck with that)</sub>.

The easy solution, is to **not use `alert()`** (ever?). Instead, if you want to debug something in your code, use `console.log` which won't stop the normal execution of your script.

Your fixed snippet.

```js
var Keys = [];

var FrameLoop = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
window.webkitrequestAnimationFrame || window.mozrequestAnimationFrame || 
window.msrequestAnimationFrame;
window.requestAnimationFrame = FrameLoop;

window.onload = GameChange();

function GameChange() {
    if (Keys[39] == true) {
        console.log("right");
    }
    FrameLoop(GameChange);
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(k) {
    Keys[k.keyCode] = true;
});

document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(k) {
    Keys[k.keyCode] = false;
    console.log('keyup');
});
onfocus = function(){document.body.className="focus"};
onblur = function(){document.body.className=""};
```

```css
.focus > p {opacity: 0}
```

```html
<p>click here to gain focus</p>
```

Comment: Nope, i don't think that was the problem because i just changed that alert("right") to document.write("right") and i just got the same result in text form.

Comment: Who told you to use `document.write`? It's even worse as it will remove all the event handlers you did attach on your document and its children. Ps: I added a fixed snippet

Comment: Sorry, you actually were right, i tried  a completely different code to further test this and it worked!